# Can't load static file while in route "/post/:postId" in spark-java framework

Tags: java, freemarker, spark-java

In my spark-java project, I put css file and js file into folder `static` in `src/main/resources`. I use `Spark.staticFileLocation("/static")` to set the static file path.

When I use `get("/posts", (req, res) ->{...})`, css and js file can load correctly. The path is `http://0.0.0.0:4567/css/style.css`, it works well.

But when I want to get the single post by postId `get("/post/:postId", (req, res) ->{...})`, it can't load the css and js file correctly. The path become `http://0.0.0.0:4567/post/css/style.css`, it can't work.

How to fix such these problem?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to fix it.

Instead of using `req.params("postId")` to get the params in `"/post/:postId"`, I change the route to `"http://0.0.0.0:4567/post?postId=1"`, so I can get the params by using `req.queryParams("postId")`, and still using the `get("/post", (req, res)->{})`.

It this situation, the static file path will be correct. It still be `http://0.0.0.0:4567/css/style.css`.